# Elasticsearch: Using of field analyser in query_string

Tags: elasticsearch

I just want to do a query_string using the analyzer of each field and not one for all fields

Do i have to specify all fields like

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "fields" : ["content", "name", ...],
            "query" : "this AND that"
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a solution ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `_all` is deprecated as of 6.0. Source: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html

Article suggests to create a custom field which can be analyzed in a way you want and searched against. Sample

```json
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "first_name": {
          "type": "text",
          "copy_to": "fake_all" 
        },
        "last_name": {
          "type": "text",
          "copy_to": "fake_all" 
        },
        "fake_all": {
          // Here you can define analyzer you want
          // And use this field four your query_string query
          "type": "text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i don't want to use _all, i want to use each field analyser

Comment: @soi Can you rephrase your question then? I'm unclear and would like to help you.

Comment: i just want to do a query_string using the analyzer of each field and not one for all fields